# Representing Log(z) as a series about z=1 from Log'(z)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

I am doing a homework quesiton at the moment and have a question which says to find that a series exapansion about z=1 for Log(z)

So far I have this
Since $Log'(z)$ = $\frac{1}{z}$ we can turn this into a series representation by
$\frac {1}{1-(-(z+1))}$

from here, I just wanted to ask if anyone could refresh for me a series I could use for this - I am thinking geomtric series but have forgotten the conditions.

After this I was thinking of integration to deduce a series representation for $Log(z)$

Any help please? :)

Comment: What's wrong with the Taylor's series?  It is fine if expanded around z = 1.

Comment: Just careful on your radius not being larger than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a new variable $w=z-1.$ Then $z=w+1$ and
$$\ln{z}=\ln(1+w), \\
\dfrac{d}{dz}{(\ln{z})}=\dfrac{1}{z}=\dfrac{1}{1+w}=\dfrac{1}{1-(-w)}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-w)^n}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n (z-1)^n}.$$
The series converges for $|w|<1,$ respectively $|z-1|<1.$

Comment: perfect! thank you very much!